# Populate Combobox with table fields and use to insert into new record

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I am entering new employees into a database via WinForms.

I have `Company` table that looks like:

```
+----------+--------------+
| CMPNY_ID |   CMPNY_NM   |
+----------+--------------+
|    01    |      ABC     |
+----------+--------------+
|    02    |      DEF     |
+----------+--------------+
```

I want to populate a Combobox so the user sees `CMPNY_NM` --> "ABC".
When the user enters a new employee, they can choose a company name.
The `CMPNY_ID` associated with the`CMPNY_NM` they chose would be added to the employee's record.

If you were entering a new record you would enter in Employee first name, last name, and select from the combobox `ABC`. That would then hold the PK associated with ABC --> "`01`" and would be inserted into the database with the rest of the information. The data would look like:

```
+----------+--------------+------------+
|  EMP_ID  |    EMP_NM    |  CMPNY_ID  |
+----------+--------------+------------+
|    01    |      ABC     |     01     |
+----------+--------------+------------+
```

I don't have much, but so far I have:

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SQLTEST_HR,4000\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True")

    Dim qry As String

    qry &= "SELECT CMPNY_SEQ_ID, CMPNY_NM"
    qry &= "FROM CMPNY"

    conn.Open()
    Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(qry, conn)
        da.Fill(ds, "CMPNY")
    End Using

    With PaymentCbx
        .DisplayMember = "CMPNY_NM"
        .DataSource = ds.Tables("CMPNY")
        .SelectedIndex = 0
    End With

    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
```

Which doesn't seem to be doing anything, really.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just missing the combo box's ValueMember.  DisplayMember sets what's displayed in the combobox, and ValueMember selects the value that the displayed value represents.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SQLTEST_HR,4000\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True")

Dim qry As String = "SELECT CMPNY_SEQ_ID, CMPNY_NM FROM CMPNY"

conn.Open()
Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(qry, conn)
    da.Fill(dt)
End Using

With PaymentCbx
    .DisplayMember = "CMPNY_NM"
    .ValueMember = "CMPNY_SEQ_ID"
    .DataSource = dt
    .SelectedIndex = 0
End With

MyBase.OnLoad(e)
```

In your button click event, once your user fills out the rest of the information, you can get the value by using the .SelectedValue property of the combo box.

```
Dim companyId as Integer = PaymentCbx.SelectedValue
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Still nothing unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: What part is missing?  You'll need to grab the value of the dropdown box when you do your insert of the new database table using PaymentCbx.SelectedValue.  I guess I'm not totally clear on what's not happening.

Comment: I added your line: `.ValueMember = "CMPNY_ID"` and ran my WinForm and the dropdown was still empty (no data)

Comment: AH, gotcha.  Could you use a DataTable rather than a DataSet as your DataSource?  (Editing above)

Comment: When I switched to DataTable, I am receiving a weird error: Error 1 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Fill' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Function Fill(startRecord As Integer, maxRecords As Integer, ParamArray dataTables() As System.Data.DataTable) As Integer': Value of type 'System.Data.DataTable' cannot be converted to 'Integer'.
    'Public Function Fill(dataSet As System.Data.DataSet, srcTable As String) As Integer': Value of type 'System.Data.DataTable' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataSet'. I have not changed anything else..

Comment: This is weird, but I decided to try and copy & paste your code into my project and now it works. No more error. So as far as getting the ValueMember stored in a variable and using it in my insert statement? Can you update your answer or have a suggestion?

Comment: Sure, see if the above works.  Edit- I think your error was happening because in the adapter.Fill method, you were still trying to give the table a name, and you don't need to do that if it's a dataTable, rather than a dataAdapter

Comment: Real quick - would this be at the top of the code below `Public Class FormName`since I will be holding the value after the user chooses it and using it in my `INSERT` statement?

Comment: I imagine your save is is done via a button click event, you could do it right there in that.  You don't even have to save it as a variable, as the ComboBox exists as a component on your form, you can just reference PaymentCbx.SelectedValue when you do your save.

Comment: You're correct! Got it. It was actually .SelectedValue.ToString

Comment: Oh, great.  Ignore my response before the edit then. :)

Comment: Is the default value of a combobox to start with the first selected record?

Comment: Yes, but you can change it after you load it if you'd like with the .SelectedValue property.  You should also just be able to set the text of it -- PaymentCbx.Text = " - Select - "

Answer (score 2):

try this
ON FORM LOAD

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING")

    Dim qry As String = ""

    qry &= "SELECT CMPNY_ID, CMPNY_NM "
    qry &= " FROM CMPNY"

    conn.Open()
    Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(qry, conn)
        da.Fill(ds, "CMPNY")
    End Using

    PaymentCbx.DataSource = ds.Tables("CMPNY")
    PaymentCbx.DisplayMember = "CMPNY_NM"
    PaymentCbx.ValueMember = "CMPNY_ID"
    PaymentCbx.SelectedIndex = 0
```

and on Combobox SelectedValueChanged event write code

```
 Dim companyid As String = PaymentCbx.SelectedValue.ToString
```

Comment: Great -Thank you! (Your code is C#, but I appreciate it nonetheless). If I wanted to give a variable to `PaymentCbx.SelectedValue.ToString()` would it need to be Public or something to use in a different Sub? (When I am clicking the 'Add' button, per si)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately Jeremy was first (and he needs the rep boost =P ). Thank you for your help and clarity.